# BOT Framework in Python and Bot service is in C# will it work?

Tags: python, c#, botframework, rest, azure-bot-service

We created a Bot using Python SDK V4. Now we want to create the bot with REST API in Azure.

As per Microsoft site's suggestion, we need to create API service in C# or Node.js.

### Questions

1. Do the Bot Framework and the REST API need to be in the same language like in Python?
2. If the Bot Framework is in Python language and the Bot API service is in C# will it work? If yes, how will they connect with each other?

Comment: You haven't told us anything about this bot, so I don't see how your question is answerable.

Comment: What do you mean by "Microsoft site's suggestion"? What Microsoft site are you talking about? What suggestions are you talking about? Are you talking about Azure? Is there a document you can link to? Also, what do you mean by "API service"? Are you talking about Azure resources? Are you talking about the Azure Web App Bot resource? If so, then you're actually picking the language of the bot and not the language of ABS, so that's irrelevant since you already have a Python bot. (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: Hi Kyle, we created bot using python SDK v4.

Comment: Hi Kyle, we created bot using python SDK v4. Now we are deploying it in web app in Azure. Our next step we are planning to connect bot using Rest Api. Now we are planning to create Rest Api in C# language. So question is that can we are able to call the python bot which is on web app azure using C# Rest Api?. If yes then how we can achieve it.

Comment: We are used below microsoft site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/index-bf-sdk?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: @abhishek - Why didn't you @ mention me? Anyway, your question is still unintelligible but I attempted an answer

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

A REST API receives and responds to HTTP requests. A Microsoft Bot Framework bot is a web app service and can be considered a REST API. There is also the Bot Framework REST API that exists separately from the individual bots, and Bot Framework bots send requests to the Bot Framework REST API in order to send messages to various channels. Any rest API can communicate with any other REST API regardless of what language they're written in. They all use HTTP so the protocol is the same.